# Basic operations are not working in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Even copy/paste and basic short cuts keys(Ctrl + F, Ctrl + k...) also not working. I am using Eclipse J2EE Juno IDE. it almost latest version. This problem is occurring after 2 or 3 hours use of Eclipse, but now it happening in just in few mins.

Just now I verified, I got this problem and so I closed Eclipse and reopen, even just in 2 mins same issue is happening. Day to day this issue wasting much time.

This is making lot of disturbance and very difficult to stop all my running applications and restart.

I am using SVN, Grails, Code Collaborator plugins only. And my laptop is 8GB RAM, Windows 7.

Comment: There may be a message in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your eclipse is corrupted and you ll need a new eclipse installation. I faced this problem last month. When I re installed, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just try another updated build of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded new Eclipse Kepler, it looks problem resolved and all my plugins also working fine. My friends answers also correct, but it is bug in Eclipse Juno, If i re-install same Eclipse Juno again, i will get same problem again.

Comment: Rather than posting the solution back, you should mark the existing answer as accepted. Click the tick mark besides the answer to mark it accepted.